# Google Charts - Multi-series, dynamic line chart from external text file

Tags: php, dynamic, charts, google-visualization

I am attempting to create a dynamic line chart in google charts, using external data from a text file. I am able to get a single-series chart working, but have not had any success additional series. What I am trying:

X Axis: Time (not a required data point and I can remove if needed)
Y Axis: Client and Value

## *#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*

**Update: After playing around with the code, the screenshot below is where I'm stuck. I've updated the code and source text/csv data below to reflect the results in the screenshot:**

[image]

Example of my text file:

```
12:00 1 -63
12:00 2 -57
1:00 1 -65
1:00 2 -51
2:00 1 -53
2:00 2 -47
3:00 1 -63
3:00 2 -57
4:00 1 -65
4:00 2 -51
5:00 1 -53
5:00 2 -47
```

HTML/PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);



  function drawChart () {
function datarefresh () {
      $.ajax({
          url: '/hsd/tmp/24SignalStrength.csv',
          type: 'get',
          success: function (txt) {
              var dataArray = [['Time','Client','Value']];
              var txtArray = txt.split('\n');
              for (var i = 0; i < txtArray.length; i++) {
                  var tmpData = txtArray[i].split(/\s+/);
                  dataArray.push([(tmpData[0]), parseInt(tmpData[1]), parseInt(tmpData[2])]);
              }
              var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);
              var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
              var options = {
        'title':'2.4GHz Connected Clients Signal Strength',
        'width':800,'height':600,
        'curveType':'function',
//      legend: 'none'
};
              chart.draw(data,options);
          }
      });
  }

setInterval(datarefresh, 1000);
}
  google.load('visualization', '2', {packages:['corechart'], callback: drawChart});


</script>
    </head>


 <body>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the number of clients is not static. In some cases it will 3 clients, others 5, etc.. Thank you again.

Comment: what are you trying to do with client? do you want a line for each different client?

Comment: Correct - I am attempting to continuously monitor signal level, by client. The 2 required variables would be: a) clients (as they can leave/join at any time), and b) signal level.

I added a timestamp since this would be measured over time, however that's less important to me as it should follow the sequence recorded to the logs.

Thank you for your response!